# New Relic mobile monitoring with Android Studio and maven project

Tags: android, android-studio, newrelic

I am using Android Studio and have maven android application. I want to add New Relic monitoring to it. I do what is in an instruction on New Relic site and have different behaviours depends on how I build the app. New Relic gathers data if I build the app by maven in console. But it doesn't work if I simply click run in Android Studio. Does anybody know why?

I think that problem may be in the New Relic agent-maven-plugin and its execution goal set to instrument. Do you know what can I do with it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

New Relic is working on an Android Studio plugin, but for the moment you will need to use either the Maven or Gradle build tools to build with New Relic instrumentation. Open a support ticket or email support@newrelic.com and we can get some details about your build environment.